# Language dependent fields

Tags: 7, entities, i18n-l10n

Is there a module that will allow me to display a field dependent on what language is selected? I have a field that I'd only like to show for Swiss pages. I tried the Conditional Fields module but it doesn't let me select the language field as the dependent.

Comment: Give a try to https://www.drupal.org/project/field_conditional_state. It works with form API elements instead of entity fields.